# Access Clipboard from Javascript API for Office app running under WinRT?

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, office365-apps

I want to read the clipboard from an Office app that lives in the Task Pane and uses the Javascript API.  Is this possible and if so, what Javascript API function(s) will let me open and read the clipboard?

My web searches have come up empty handed.  The best Javascript API for Office reference I could find was this one:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp142185(v=office.1501401).aspx

But I don't see any reference ot the clipboard in it.  Note, the app will be running inside an Office app running on WinRT (Surface 2).  I'm pointing this out in case the WinRT sandbox comes into play here.

Answer (score 0):

There is no API in *apps for office* accessing any clipboard, not the system clipboard and not the excel/word clipboard widget.

Since IE5 there is the [clipboardData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms535220%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) object, which lets read and write the system clipboard.